# Passport Authentication and login redirection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, passport.js

I have two types of user: Admin and Tester.

What I am trying to do: If the user that logs in is an Admin, render 'dashboardA'. If not, render 'dashboard'.

I don't know how to do this and attempted and failed. Below is my code. I'm a novice

**Present code**
*This works fine but it does not differentiate between the userType. I am using handlebars as template engine*

```
const User = require('../models/User');

// Login Handle
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/dashboard',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/login',
        failureFlash: true
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

**This is my failed attempt**

```
// Login Handle
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', { if(User.userType === 'Admin') {
        successRedirect: 'dashboardA',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/login',
        failureFlash: true
    } else { 
        successRedirect: 'dashboard',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/login',
        failureFlash: true
    }
        
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Does any one have ideas on how to successfully go about this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `console.log(User.userType)` returns?

Comment: @ShivamSood it returns undefined